# Execute command in Makefile only if shell command output is empty

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to run some commands only if a shell command output is empty, like this:

```
setup-database:
    database=$(shell docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -e "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name = 'dbname'" --silent --silent)

ifeq ($(strip $(database)),)
    docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -e "create database dbname"

    # ...
endif
```

but it doesn't work. It executes the commands inside the `if`, regardless the first command's output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're mixing Make commands and shell commands.

```
setup-database:
    database=$(shell docker-compose some things)
ifeq ($(strip $(database)),)
    docker-compose some other things
    # ...
endif
```

That `ifeq ... endif` is a *Make* conditional. Make will evaluate it before running any rule; the variable `database` is empty to begin with, so Make always includes that block of rules in the recipe. (And in fact the *make* variable `database` remains empty. The `database` that gets assigned a value is a *shell* variable.

Since you want to test the variable when the rule is executed, it should be a shell variable, tested with a shell conditional. On the command line, this would be:

```
database=`docker-compose some things`
if [ -z $database ]
  then
  docker-compose some other things
  ...
fi
```

(I don't think `[ -z STRING ]` cares about whitespace, so we don't need `$(strip ...)`.)

Since every command in a recipe runs in a separate subshell, the whole thing must be on one line or the value of the variable will be lost:

```
database=`docker-compose some things`; if [ -z $database ] ; then docker-compose some other things; ...; fi
```

And when we put this in a makefile, we use `$(shell ...)` instead of backticks, and escape the `$` (and optionally use some backslashes to make the rule more readable):

```
setup-database:
    database=$(shell docker-compose some things);\
  if [ -z $$database ] ; then \
  docker-compose some other things; \
  ... \
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Make does not provide direct option to extract values of specific operation into variables.
Two options to consider: - using a make symbol, tracking the result a file.

1. create make symbol

```
  # Note: nothing get executed.
db_check=$(shell docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -e "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name = 'dbname'" --silent --silent)

In setup-database:
    # Create shell variable. Useful only on the same line.
    database="${db_check}" ; [ "$database" ] || docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -e "create database dbname"

    # ...
```

Comment: So there isn't any way to execute multiple lines inside the `if`?

Comment: What about the return status? Can it be extracted into a variable?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: the return status can be extracted, but that wasn't in your Question. How do you want to use it?

Comment: Well, simply put, if the database isn't created, create it and then execute other commands.